# How do you disable logging in Vmware Server?

Tags: logging, vmware-server

I'm trying to disable log events for the `vmware-hostd` process on my system. There is a file `/etc/vmware/hostd/config.xml` that has log level settings.

What are the correct values to disable constant logging to `/var/log/vmware/hostd.log`?

Comment: Is this VMWare ESX you're talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable logging by editing the virtual machine's .vmx file, setting

```
logging="false"
```

That's described in this [Knowledge Base article](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?cmd=displayKC&externalId=8182749).  I'm not sure how to set it globally.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you're running VMware ESX and you're trying to change the logging for the host.  If so, go in through the Virtual Center GUI, select the particular ESX host, and set/reset logging for that particular host.